# How to float an image up to the image above

Tags: html, wordpress, image, margin

how can I "float" these image boxes automatically up under the image above? It's based on Wordpress, selfmade theme.
It's based on a responsive grid system.

Now it looks like this:

!now [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKlvp.png)

Should look like this:

!after [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90erd.png)

```html
<div class="section group">
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
Div 1
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
Div 1
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
Div 1
</div>
</div>
<div class="section group">
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
</div>
.....
```

```css
.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.group:after {
    clear: both;
}

.col {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col {
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

.span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span_2_of_3 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span_1_of_3 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span_3_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span_2_of_3 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span_1_of_3 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

style images in your css file and give

display:inline-block; 
property or else please share your code snippet so i can assist you more.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="section group">
<div style="height:150px;" class="col span_1_of_3">
Div 1
</div>
<div style="height:150px;" class="col span_1_of_3">
Div 1
</div>
<div style="height:180px;" class="col span_1_of_3">
Div 1
</div>
</div>
<div class="section group">
<div style="height:150px;" class="col span_1_of_3">
</div>
.....
```

it is not that efficient way to do that but it is effective other option is to use javascript function that will assign height to every box equals to the content it contains.

Comment: Let me know if you need javascript function for that .

Comment: yeah, please give me the javascript function. this doesnt work for me

Comment: sorry bro someone have deleted my answer here is the link you use this
http://masonry.desandro.com/